# send value from popup('open') to 'popupbeforeposition'

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I've a function that is triggered from a on click event. It's open up my popup, and im woundering how to send my date to my 'popupbeforeposition'.

```
    module.selectedDay = function($this) {
    var date = $this.data('date');
    $('#popupWorkSelect').popup('open');
};

    $('#popupWorkSelect').on({
    popupbeforeposition: function (event) {
        //Get date sended to this function?
        console.log(event);
    },
    popupafterclose: function(event) {

    }
});
```

I know that I can work with my 'module.selectedDay' function like this but it's not the way I want to do it.

```
    module.selectedDay = function($this) {
    var date = $this.data('date');
    $('#popupWorkSelect').find('#myElement').innerHTML = date;
    $('#popupWorkSelect').popup('open');
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When the click happens, store the value in `data` of the popup.

  ```
  $popup.data("mydata", date);
  ```
- in the `popupbeforeposition` event, take it out from data and use it. (Here the context would be within the popup so `data` you need would lie in `$(this)`. So the way of access would be this:

  ```
  $this.data("mydata")
  ```

  **Demo** : <kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/LV9VW/3/</kbd>

**PS** assume $popup and $this are the popup elements

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Weird I didn't find anything about that earlier. Thanks!